Outlook Attachment VBA Variable Reference Object required (Error 424)
I have defined and assigned all variables correctly but still getting object required (error 424) at the loop through Attachments line below:
Sub apscan()

    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strMonth As String
    Dim dReceivedTime As Date
    Dim strReceivedDate As String
    Dim i, n As Long 
    Dim strMsg As String     
    Dim nPrompt As Integer 
    Dim ns As     Namespace
    Dim folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Loc As Range
    Dim atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim atmts As Outlook.Attachments

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Set olApp = CreateObject "Outlook.Application")
    Set ns = olApp. GetNamespace ("МАРІ")
    Set folder = ns.Folders("AP").Folders("Inbox")
    Set objItems = folder.Items
    objItems.SetColumns("ReceivedTime")     
    objItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    For Each objItem In objItems
        For Each atmt In objItem.Attachments     
            Debug.Print atmt.Filename
        Next atmt
    Next objItem

End Sub


Which exact line has the error?

For Each atmt In objItem.Attachments

Comment out the line objItems.SetColumns("ReceivedTime")   "After applying the SetColumns method on specific properties of the collection, you cannot read other properties of that collection; properties which are not cached are returned empty. "  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.setcolumns#:~:text=After%20applying%20the%20SetColumns%20method%20on%20specific%20properties%20of%20the%20collection%2C%20you%20cannot%20read%20other%20properties%20of%20that%20collection%3B%20properties%20which%20are%20not%20cached%20are%20returned%20empty.

Sub apscan()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim ns As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim objItems As Object
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim atmt As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 = olFolderInbox
    Set objItems = folder.Items

    objItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

    For Each objItem In objItems
        If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then
            For Each atmt In objItem.Attachments
                Debug.Print atmt.Filename
            Next atmt
        End If
    Next objItem

    Set atmt = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objItems = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub


@KenWhite - this answer was posted a few minutes before I added my comment above.
